# Mostrar una imagen repetidamente con distintos tamaños

Tags: web, imagen, eficiencia

Estoy haciendo un sitio web que va a mostrar la misma imagen en diferentes tamaños según el lugar donde se encuentre. Si la imagen tiene el tamaño por ejemplo de 500x500 y yo la achico según el lugar donde aparezca con width="" y height="", se supone la imagen se cargaría como si fuese de 500x500 y esto no sería eficiente, el sitio demoraría más en cargar.

Tendría más sentido al subir la imagen usar las funciones para manejo de imágenes GD de php, y crear las imágenes con las dimensiones para cada sección que van a aparecer. Pero esto me haría ocupar mucho espacio porque si aparece en 3 partes con diferente tamaño crearía 3 imágenes, y así por todas las que suba.

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de mostrar una imagen repetidas veces con diferentes dimensiones?

Comment: Te recomendaría tratar de acomodar tu texto para que se entienda mejor, esta todo pegado.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta no cumple con los estándares de calidad del sitio y debe ser cerrada.

Comment: como esta todo pegado? es una pregunta que no implica codigo fuente como queres que lo escriba?

Comment: Deberías añadir más información a la pregunta: ¿la imagen va a aparecer repetida varias veces en la misma página siempre o sólo algunas veces? ¿Alguna de las veces que aparezca va a ser con el tamaño original? Si la imagen va a aparecer al menos una vez en su tamaño original, no importa que la incluyas más veces cambiando el tamaño con los atributos `height` y `width` porque los navegadores la van a cargar una sola vez de todos modos.

Answer (score 1):

La opcion mas eficiente que quieres seria la que yo uso con laravel php, y es crear una ruta tipo /500x500/imagen1.jpg y con php retornar la imagen ya manipulada a ese tamaño a partir de la imagen original, con laravel es facil con php puro tendrias que hacer todo manual. Pero ya solamente tendrias que cambiar los valores eje: /100x50/imagen1.jpg o /100x500/imagen1.jpg etc.

Comment: Vos creas carpetas por ej big-thumb, medium-thumb, small-thumb y cuando subis una imagen creas una para cada carpeta? con las dimensiones correspondientes obvio?

Comment: @FernandoRossi con este método no hace falta tener múltiples directorios/carpetas. La imagen se subiría una sola vez y se sirve en el tamaño especificado (cortada/escalada al vuelo).

Comment: Solo subes la imagen una sola vez en original sin manipular su tamaño, solo cuando llamas a la url de la imagen se haria el proceso en php de redimensionarla a los valores pasados por la url y retornarla nada mas.